# How soon should I accept an answer and when is it appropriate to accept a different answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, answers, accepting

How soon should I accept an answer?

As I understand it, you should accept the answer that is *most* helpful. Often the first answer I receive fixes my problem, but then someone else posts an answer with a simpler solution that is easier to implement or in some way better or more helpful.

What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ultimately, which answer is accepted is down to you, so in a sense you decide on this. That said, I would normally expect to wait 24 h after posting a question to see if there are multiple answers. Once a question is marked as 'accepted', there will be slightly less interest in checking it over from other users. At the same time, remember that you can change your mind here. Over time, what is the best answer may change, so don't feel bad about moving that tick mark.